Why can't I format my dates after they are returned from this function?
I have a Google sheet which takes dates and then uses this function.
function nextDueDate(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, done1, done2, done3, done4, done5, done6) {
  const today = new Date();
  const dates = [new Date(date1), new Date(date2), new Date(date3),new Date(date4), new Date(date5), new Date(date6)];
  var dones = [done1, done2, done3, done4, done5, done6];

  // Completes earlier tasks if subsequent tasks are completed
  var dones = dones.map((val,index) => { if(dones.lastIndexOf('x')>=index ) {return 'x'}});

  // Filter for dates that are not done
  const futureDates = dates.filter((date,index) => !dones[index]);

  // Find the earliest date from the filtered future dates
  const nextDueDate = futureDates.reduce((earliest, date) => {
    return date < earliest ? date : earliest;
  }, new Date('2999-12-31')); // initial date far in the future

  // If the nextDueDate year is still in the far future then all tasks are done (on no dates)
  return (nextDueDate.getFullYear() === 2999) ? 'DELETE' : nextDueDate.toLocaleDateString(); // Returns the next due date in a readable format
}

After the date is returned, the dates are formatted like this: 2024-06-26. But I want to be able to custom format them as 'Wed 26 June'. But when I try to change the date formatting it stays the same. I assume it's not returning as a normal date object. How do I get it to convert to a date type I can then re-format?

The way you deal with dones seems to suggest that the dates are provided in sorted order. Is this so?

Changing the last line to this will return the date format you're looking for.
return (nextDueDate.getFullYear() === 2999) ? 'DELETE' : Utilities.formatDate(nextDueDate, "GMT", "EEE dd MMM"); // Returns the next due date in a readable format


Thanks so much. You've been a huge help.
